# out of memory in matlab run time

Tags: matlab, loops, for-loop, mathematical-optimization

I wrote code in matlab r2014a for predicting target user rate to the target item. in my method i assign weight to the items by computing item similarity between target item and each of corated items between target user and another user. after i computing items similarities (ISIM) and catch it to memory should compute user similarities base on isim.
but i face with out of memory error. i have 1206 user and 1508 item in my dataset.
traindata = 1206x1508
isim = 1508x1508
isim and user similarity formulas are as below:

[image](isim)

[image](user similarity with respect to isim)

and my code is below

```
load('isim.mat');
        isim2 = isim.^2;
        for i = 1 : size(traindata,1)
            target_user = traindata(i,:);
            mean_target_user = repmat(mean(target_user),length(target_user),1);
             for k = i+1 : size(traindata,1)
                 second_user = traindata(k,:);
                 mean_second_user = repmat(mean(second_user),length(second_user),1);
                 for z = 1 : size(isim , 1)
                 pearson{i,k}{z} = sum(isim(z,:) .*(target_user - (mean_target_user')).*(second_user - (mean_second_user')))/sqrt((sum(isim(z,:) .*(target_user - (mean_target_user')).^2)))*sqrt(sum((isim(z,:).*(second_user - (mean_second_user')).^2))); 
mean(target_user))*(traindata(k,z)-mean(traindata(k,:)))/sqrt(isim(j,z)*(traindata(i,z)-mean(target_user))^2)*sqrt(isim{j}(z)*(traindata(k,z)-mean(traindata(k,:)))^2);

                 end
             end  

        end
```

Comment: First hint: preallocate your variables (if not already). Second hint: reduce the computation amount (number of traindata) until it works, then do `whos` and check how large they are

Comment: thank u so much dear Robert, i can reduce number of train data but i want to use my method's result in my paper and need acceptable amount of train data to show efficiency of it.

Comment: Here is why I said it: when you reduce it to the point where it works, maybe you can deduce what the problem is. With `whos` you can check the size of your variables and find the problematic ones